# Load php page into view via jQuery load() in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter-3

I need to refresh div contents with single php pages via jQuery.
Without CodeIgniter it works in jQuery like this:

```
$(".myDIV").load("my_page.php");
```

As I am using CodeIgniter I tried to solve it with setting the base_url but it does not work:

```
$(".myDIV").load("<?php echo base_url()."application/views/my_page.php"; ?>");
```

How do I call the include request via jQuery correctly?

Comment: load the controller ?

Comment: $(".myDIV").load("<?php echo base_url(); ?>controller_name/function_name");

Comment: Normally you wouldn't load a view, you would load the controller. If you're using routes, you would do `<?php echo base_url()."/my_page"; ?>` or something.

Comment: what is your controller name?

Comment: Thanks to all replies! Helped me to solve this issue. Just call the controller and there load the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In controller My_page_ctrl.php

```
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('my_page');
    }
```

In javascript

```
$(".myDIV").load("<?php echo base_url().'my_page_ctrl'; ?>");
```

Try this one. This will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

just call the name of function in controller

```
public function my_page(){
    $this->load->view('my_page');
}


$(".myDIV").load("my_page");
```

It works !